# Java Exit Button from a MenuItem/MenuBar and Sound Player

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

Ok, i wrote this pice of code as an beginner in java learning from videos/school, and i got some questions.

**1 =>** Why the **File > Exit** button is not working and have a small arrow as if having some childs? The big exit button works with the same function.
I have been inspired from here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?src_vid=FB_wJpIdA8k&feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_40248&v=dwLkDGm5EBc

**2 =>** How can i make that button smaller? It's bigger when i resize it.

**3 =>** Does anyone know a simple sound player library? So when i press that button to play a sound? I have tryied some web examples, like http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2173111/Java-Sound-Playing-Back-Audio-Files-using-Java.htm and don't know how to make it simple and use it everywhere like SoundPlay(sound.au);

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class form4 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Menu");
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Just create menubar
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

        // Add an JMenu
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        menubar.add(file);
        // Add an JMenuItem
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenu("Exit");
        file.add(exit);
        exit.addActionListener(new exitApp());

        // Add an JMenu
        JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
        menubar.add(help);
        // Add an JMenuItem
        JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
        help.add(about);

        // Add an JButton
        JButton exitButton= new JButton("Exit!");
        frame.add(exitButton);
        exitButton.addActionListener(new exitApp());
        exitButton.setSize(40,40);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Exit app
    static class exitApp implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: See [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) regarding submenus.

Comment: See also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To make the exit menu work, use a JMenuItem:

```
  JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
  exit.addActionListener(new exitApp());
  file.add(exit);
```

Regarding your other question, how to make the button "smaller", you need to understand that you're adding this JButton to a JFrame's contentPane, and that contentPane's use BorderLayout by default. So adding the button in this way will make it fill up the container completely. To prevent this from happening, you'll need to use other layouts. Please read up on how to use Swing Layouts for the details: [A Visual Guide to the Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: works, it was my mistake, i have to look more carefully, because i'm new to java. Thank you :)

Comment: anyway, is there a visual button interface, like in C# in java? i currently use Eclipse ...

Comment: @RowMinds: Explain "visual button interface" as that has no meaning to me. If you're asking if there's a visual GUI designer similar to MS Visual Studio, then yes, there is, but I strongly urge you not to use it til you learn the rudiments of Swing.

Comment: It wont run, my IDE says this: "exitApp cannot be resolved to a type" how can i fix it

Comment: @jakobaindreas_11: seriously. Please re-read the question before reading the answers.

Answer (score 4):

Below is how i implement it in my applications, hope it helps:

```
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    mainWindow.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    mntmClose = new JMenuItem("Close");
    mntmClose.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
    mntmClose.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
             KeyEvent.VK_Q, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    mntmClose.setToolTipText("Exit application");
    mntmClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    });
    mnFile.add(mntmClose);
```

Comment: Good answer, and where do you put this?

Comment: Apologies for necro but since Java 8 you can replace that bulky code piece with this lambda:```mntmClose.addActionListener(event -> System.exit(0));```